# Decimal points and time are showing in db2 and not in Oracle

Tags: oracle, db2, migration

I'm migrating from db2 to Oracle database. Can someone pls explain why decimal points and time are showing in db2 but not in Oracle. Is there any specific reason?

For ex:

1. 1000.000 in db2 and 1000 in Oracle SQL developer.
2. 2022-07-22 08:23:06 in db2 and 202-07-22 in Oracle.

Checked in db2visualizer and Oracle SQL developer.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle databases **store** `NUMBER`s and `DATE`s as binary values in a non-human readable format and you **CANNOT** change how they are stored.

If you want to **display** values in a certain way then use `TO_CHAR` and specify the format you want them to display as.

---

In Oracle:

- `NUMBER`s are stored by **value** in a binary format with 1-byte per 2-digits and are **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format. `1000` and `1000.000` are identical in value so the database will only ever store `1000` and never store any trailing zero-value decimal digits.
- `DATE`s are stored in a binary format consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and seconds. It **ALWAYS** has all of those date and time components and is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

When you query the database, it will return the binary values to the client application and then the client application chooses how to **display** that binary data to the user in a meaningful way.

If you, as the user, want to change how the client **displays** the data then you can either:

1. Modify the settings on the client application. For SQL Developer, you can change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter or change the settings in the preferences menu (there is no setting on the client to show number to a specific number of decimal places); or
2. Use `TO_CHAR` to format the binary values as a string in your desired format.

   ```sql
   SELECT TO_CHAR(your_number_column, '9999D000') AS your_formatted_number,
          TO_CHAR(your_date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS your_formatted_date
   FROM   your_table;
   ```

Comment: There isn't a setting for decimal places in the preferences, but you can use [`set numformat 9999D000`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-BEC116D1-AEF3-499F-BDAB-4EAC4A149655) in a worksheet script (which doesn't affect result grids, sadly).